# viewModelScope is cancelled in viewPager

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewpager, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

there are  fragments in viewPager and each fragment has a viewModel.

when viewpager's current item changes ,fragment is destroyed ,viewModel onCleared is called and viewModelScope is cancelled

there are 2 problems , first after returning back to same fragment, viewModelScope is cancelled and can't launch any coroutines. second when viewPager's current item is changing , the launched coroutine is cancelled.

how can i solve this issues?

i use FragmentStatePagerAdapter with BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT and OffscreenPageLimit is the default value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something during the application run lifecycle. You could use `ProcessLifecycleOwner`. like below.

```
ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().launch {
 // Do what you want.
}
```

Or even you can use shared ViewModel for each framents of viewpage.

============================== Deprecated ==================

use `GlobeScope.launch{}`

Comment: This is actually one of the way i solved it, although i'd prefer a better solution.